# Copying co-ordinates to field geo_point type using copy_to in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to work with geo code in elasticsearch, I have an index which is having two different unique field as latitude and longitude. Both are being stored as double, I want to use copy to feature of elasticsearch and copy both field value to a third field which will have geo_point type. I tried doing that but that's not working as intended.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "unique_id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "location_data": {
        "properties": {
          "latitude": {
            "type": "float",
            "copy_to": "last_location"
          },
          "longitude": {
            "type": "float",
            "copy_to": "last_location"
          },
          "last_location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I index a sample document such as

```
{
  "unique_id": "12345_mytest",
  "location_data": {
    "latitude": 37.16,
    "longitude": -124.76
  }
}
```

You will be able to see in the new mapping that the last_location field which was supposed to be inside location_data object is also populated at root level with a different data type other than geo_point.

```
{
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "last_location" : {
          "type" : "float"
        },
        "location_data" : {
          "properties" : {
            "last_location" : {
              "type" : "geo_point",
              "store" : true
            },
            "latitude" : {
              "type" : "float",
              "copy_to" : [
                "last_location"
              ]
            },
            "longitude" : {
              "type" : "float",
              "copy_to" : [
                "last_location"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "unique_id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And furthermore when I query over the field I am unable to get the result as expected.

This doesn't works, any other ideas or way to do that. I know I can do that from the source itself or by altering the data before indexing, but I don't have to luxury to do that right away. Any other way by altering the mapping is most welcome. Thanks in advance for any pointers to get this done.

Thanks 
Ashit

Comment: what doesn't work? Can you share the error message you receive?

Comment: @Nate I have updated the questions with given issues which I am seeing.